# Laravel 4 Wildcard Routing to Different Controllers

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

Realizing I'm going to take a beating for this, I have several questions about "best practices" when constructing a laravel route.

1. Do laravel routes run "first come first serve" from top to bottom?  So if a route is found, does it pass control to the controller (or perform the action) and then terminate?
2. I have a part of my application that acts as a URL shortner.  So, my route looks something like this:

```
    Route::get('/{id}', array('as' => 'home.text', 'uses' => 'HomeController@text'), function($id){
        //Make sure ID exists before pushing to controller.
        if (Storage::where('shortcode','=', $id)->count() > 0)
        {
            // route found
        }


    });
```

How can this be improved?  For one, I'm not exactly sure how to pass the processing over to the controller conditionally.. Like some sort of Controller::make() ..?

3) Is there a better way in laravel to check if a record exists versus doing

```
  Mode::where('column','=','value')->count()
```

4) I have some legacy urls that look like this http://url.com/?p=6&id=wujbl .. Can a route be designed so that it matches ?p={number}&id={id} ?  Is there a better way to process this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for route filters.  I'll post an example in a bit.

Comment: @extreme: you can't possibly take a beating - it's a decent question. And, I agree with Sajan. Route Filters are probably better. Nonetheless, there's nothing wring with what you are doing. Routes do run on a first-com-first-serve basis.

Answer (score 0):

For url shortener  you can use a catch all route and if there is an Url redirect to it otherwise you can check it for query strings.